# When $f:\mathbb N \to \mathbb R$ is $\lambda$ integrable?

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

I'm studying measure theory for tomorrow's exam and this question came up. Any help would be great!

My question is

- When is $f:\mathbb N \to \mathbb R$  $\lambda$-integrable?
- And if it is what is the  integral of $f$?

Comment: What is Lebesgue measure on the natural numbers?

Comment: To be honest i am confused.. it has to be their cardinality.Before this question there was an example: $\mu : \mathcal P \left({\mathbb N}\right)\to [0,\infty]$ where $\mu (A)= \infty$ if $A\subset \mathbb N$ infinite and $\mu(A)=|A|$ if $A$ is finite.Show that $\mu$ is measure.After that there was the previous question.I guess it has something to do with Dirac measure but I don't know..

Comment: I think your answer helped me ! 
Let $\mu(A) =\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n\delta_n(A)$ where $a_n=f$ and $\delta_n$ the Dirac measure.So $\mu$ is finite iff $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n$ is convergeant.

Comment: @Iniciador What Gerry means is that the "Lebesgue" measure is the standard measure on $\mathbb{R}$. I guess you want the counting measure which is the synonym of Lebesgue measure for $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: I think it is incorrect to call counting measure on the integers "Lebesgue measure".

Comment: Thank you for the remark,I will change it

Comment: @GEdgar I agree, but they are both Haar measures, so to me it is fine to call it the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: But it is better (and furthermore, correct) to call it Haar measure on $\mathbb Z$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\lambda$ be the counting measure on $\mathbb N$. Suppose that $f(n)=a_n$, for all $n\in\mathbb N$. Any subset of $\mathbb N$ with the counting measure is measurable, so $f$ is measurable. Now, you have that $$\int_{\mathbb N}|f(n)|\,d\lambda(n)=\int_{\mathbb N}\sum_{k\in\mathbb N}\chi_k(n)|f(n)|\,d\lambda(n)=\sum_{k\in\mathbb N}\int_{\{k\}}|f(n)|\,d\lambda(n)=\sum_{k\in\mathbb N}|f(k)|.$$ So, $f$ is integrable when the series of $(a_n)$ is asbolutely convergent. In this case, calculating as above, we have that $$\int_{\mathbb N}f(n)\,d\lambda(n)=\sum_{k\in\mathbb N}\int_{\{k\}}f(n)\,d\lambda(n)=\sum_{k\in\mathbb N}f(k)=\sum_{k\in\mathbb N}a_k.$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $\mu(A) =\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n\delta_n(A)$ where $a_n=f$ and $\delta_n$ the Dirac measure.So $\mu$ is finite iff $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n$ is convergeant.

Comment: Good, but the question was "when is $f$ integrable, and what is its integral?" You have to answer the question in the terms in which it was stated; "$f$ is integrable when ...."